# Can see JSON data in console, can't render to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, console

I'm pulling JSON data from a local file. If the data is `true` then I want to append it to a div, if not then it shouldn't appear at all.

I can see the `true` data in `console.log` so now it's a matter of appending it, but I'm running into an issue with my `return` statement (see code below). Any thoughts?

#### JS snippet:

```
import testjson from './test.json';

    function loadTopCourses() {
        let isTop = testjson.d.results.filter(x => x.TopTrainingCourse === true) {
            return {
                "Title": val.Title
            }
        };

        console.log(isTop)

        let showTopTitles = isTop;

        for (var i = 0; i < showTopTitles.length; i++) {
            let li = $("<li></li>");
            $(li).append(showTopTitles[i].Title);
            $(".top-training-ul").append(li)
        };

    } // ------------------ loadTopCourses

    loadTopCourses();
```

#### JSON snippet:

```
{
   "d": {
     "results": [
       {
         ...
         "Id": 1,
         "Title": "Training 1",
         "Category": "Enter Choice #1",
         "Topic": "Enter Choice #1",
         "Description": "My Test description",
         "TopTrainingCourse": false, // ------------ //
         "ID": 1,
         "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:13:46Z",
         "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:36Z"
       },
...
...
"FileSystemObjectType": 0,
         "Id": 2,
         "Title": "Training 2",
         "Category": "Enter Choice #2",
         "Topic": "Enter Choice #1",
         "Description": null,
         "TopTrainingCourse": true, // ------------- //
         "ID": 2,
         "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:14:00Z",
         "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:53Z"
       },
...
...
```

#### console.log:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] // ------ correct # of true values
0: {__metadata: {…}, FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject: {…}, RoleAssignments: {…}, AttachmentFiles: {…}, ContentType: {…}, …}
1:
ID: 4
Id: 4
Modified: "2019-03-05T22:33:04Z"
OData__UIVersionString: "1.0"
ParentList: {__deferred: {…}}
RoleAssignments: {__deferred: {…}}
Title: "Training 4"
TopTrainingCourse: true // ------------- //
Topic: "Enter Choice #1"
```

Comment: `let li = $("<li></li>");
            $(li).append(showTopTitles[i].Title);` don't you think your `li`  is closed before you append the data to it. You should close your `</li>` after data is appended to it.. then only it will be like this `<li>test data</li>`

Comment: let li = $("<li></li>"); This line seems wrong, in jquery, you have to put a selector $("li"). But in your case try something more like this in your for loop; let li = "<li>"+showTopTitles[i].Title+"</li>"; and then adding it by using  $(".top-training-ul").append(li)

Comment: @nircraft @Nico My code worked for me but yeah it looked pretty clunky. I updated it so the `append` is now on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` the filtered results into a new array of the form that you want:

```js
let isTop = testjson.d.results.filter(x => x.TopTrainingCourse === true)
.map(x => { return { Title: x.Title } });
```